# Issue in Bash script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a bash script which creates a directory if not already present and moves all the files to the newly created directory.

The bash script I have is returning is not working and the error is receive is

```
./move.sh: line 5: =/data/student/stud_done_11-11-2013: No such file or directory

already present
mv: missing destination file operand after `a.xml'
Try `mv --help' for more information.
```

The bash script is:

```
# Back up

if [ $# = 1 ]
then
  $dir="/data/student/stud_done_$1"
  echo $dir
  if [ ! -d $dir ]; then
    mkdir $dir
  else
    echo "already present"
  fi
  cd  /data/student/stud_ready
  mv * $dir
else
  echo "No files to move"
fi
```

I invoke the script as follows:

```
./move.sh "11-11-2013"
```

What is the error in my script.

Answer (score 2):

Here (on line 5)...

```
$dir="/data/student/stud_done_$1"
```

You meant...

```
dir="/data/student/stud_done_$1"
```